# An additional text, data, and bss section for each shared library in process's address space, is this true?

Tags: process, linux-kernel

An additional text, data, and bss section for each shared library, such as the C library and dynamic linker, loaded into the process's address space(http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch14)

is above statement is true if yes than how?

can anyone explain?

Answer (score 6):

It's correct. The text section is executable code. The data section is initialized data, so any global or static variables are placed here. The bss section is uninitialized data (i.e. implicitly initialized to zeroes) declared by the library code.

So, given this C code:

```
int my_flag = 1;

char my_buf[100];

void my_func(void) {
   strcpy(my_buf, "Hello, world\n");
   my_flag = 0;
}
```

my_func goes into the text section, my_flag goes into data, and my_buf goes into bss.

When loaded, the dynamic linker will arrange separate areas of memory for each section, and initialize them with (text) executable code from the library's text section [with relocations applied], (data) the initialized data from the library's data section, (bss) zeroed pages to the size specified for the library's bss section.

To see how this looks in an actual process, try:

```
cat /proc/self/maps
```

This will display the memory map of the cat process itself. (You can look at other processes via `/proc/<pid>/maps`.)

Note that there is no file name recorded with bss sections since, once the size is determined, there is no need to know the file name. The text and data sections OTOH each have the file name recorded in association with them because code and data pages are dynamically loaded from the file via page faults as the program execution proceeds.

Comment: you mean if my program share one library than in process address space have two data section, two bss section (one for program code and one for shared library),please explain

Comment: Yes. Every additional library will have its own text, data and bss sections.

Comment: how we can check this additional area,Like for libc shared lobrary if we see maps of process it show only area for libc.so

Comment: What are you trying to do? libc.so *is* the shared library. "shared library" == "shared object"